# CSS: create material design shadow issue

Tags: html, css, shadow, dropshadow

[image]

I need to create this button with CSS only and have an issue with box shadow. There are two different shadows on this button: one yellow, one black. The maximum what I get is this

```css
.button {
  height: 81px;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Celias_Medium', 'Open Sans:500', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 3.3;
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 23px 0 26px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #fbfb5c;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 90px -30px rgba(251, 251, 92, 0.9), 0 40px 90px -50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
```

```html
<div class="button">ADD 7 Activities</div>
```

Here is [result](https://jsfiddle.net/m1vdbewh/). Is there any other solution to get this result?

Comment: https://codepen.io/sdthornton/pen/wBZdXq

Comment: I don't really understand what the question is here, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

try on this if u cant see it on chrome moz or safari

```
.button {
    height: 81px;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Celias_Medium', 'Open Sans:500', sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 3.3;
    letter-spacing: 0.4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 23px 0 26px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #fbfb5c;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 90px -30px rgba(251, 251, 92, 0.9), 0 40px 90px -50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 90px -30px rgba(251, 251, 92, 0.9), 0 40px 90px -50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 90px -30px rgba(251, 251, 92, 0.9), 0 40px 90px -50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

hope this one works :)

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```css
.button {
        height: 81px;
        width: 250px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Celias_Medium', 'Open Sans:500', sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        line-height: 3.3;
        letter-spacing: 0.4px;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
        display: block;
        vertical-align: top;
        padding: 23px 0 26px 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #fbfb5c;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 70px -24px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="button">
  ADD y activities
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking material buttons would look something like this, but I don't really know what you're asking.

```css
.button {
  height: 81px;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Celias_Medium, 'Open Sans:500', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 3.3;
  letter-spacing: .4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 23px 0 26px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #fbfb5c;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 16px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
  transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1)
}
.button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .22)
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  Button no. 1
</div>
<div class="button">
  Button no. 2
</div>
<div class="button">
  Button no. 3
</div>
<div class="button">
  Button no. 4
</div>
<div class="button">
  Button no. 5
</div>
```